# PHP not executing in order

Tags: php, exec, sleep

I'm having trouble with a PHP script that I'm using to configure the WiFi network in a Raspberry Pi 3. It's supposed to get the SSID and PW variables from POST, answer an "ok" to the ajax call and then execute the script (in that order, after that the RPi reboots so the connection is lost). The problem is that the script is being executed BEFORE sending the "ok" response. Here is the code:

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('content-type: text/html; charset:utf-8');
    require_once "chkSession.php";
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username_db = "xxx";
    $password_db = "xxx";
    $dbname = "xxx";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username_db, $password_db, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("died" . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $sessionKey = $_POST['sessionKey'];

    if (chkSession($conn,$username,$sessionKey)){
        $ssid = $_POST['ssid'];
        $wifipwd = $_POST['wifipwd'];
        echo json_encode(["auth"=>"ok"]);
        sleep(5);
        exec("sudo /var/www/scripts/configwifi.sh \"".$ssid."\" \"".$wifipwd."\"");
    } else {
        echo json_encode(["auth"=>"skErr"]);
    }
?>
```

As you can see, the `exec` is... well, executed five secs after sending the "ok" response. Or should be, but the response is not arriving.

I've searched for similar questions, but haven't really found anything useful (or similar).

EDIT:

I've tried what @steven-jackson answered, with no results:

```
echo json_encode(["auth"=>"ok"]);
flush();
ob_flush();
sleep(5);
exec("sudo /var/www/scripts/configwifi.sh \"".$ssid."\" \"".$wifipwd."\"");
```

EDIT 2:

Tried changing the `sleep` from the php script to the shell script, executing it as `exec("sudo /var/www/scripts/configwifi.sh \"".$ssid."\" \"".$wifipwd."\" &");`, but didn't work either.

Comment: This is to be expected. The ok message is going to be sent to the buffer and then not released until the end of the script.

Comment: I'm guessing you are experiencing session locking, I don't see the `$_SESSION` variable in your script but I would assume its in the `chkSession.php` files so ... to solve this place the code `session_write_close();` above your `echo` statement.

Comment: @cmorrissey Actually I'm not using PHP sessions for user validation, `chkSession.php` is a script that I wrote for a simple session validation (basically it just checks that the session key sent by the user matches the one stored in the server).

Comment: @RossWilson Is there a way to circumvent this? I had no idea that all of the script's output was buffered before sending it, I thought that it could send individual echoes.

Comment: Might be a silly question but does apache/nginx/whatever is executing the script have a NOPASSWD set in sudoers? edit: NM it seems like you said your script is executing fine.

Comment: @StevenJackson It does, `www-data` can sudo commands inside `/var/www/scripts/` (and nowhere else). It does execute well, problem is that it fails to answer "ok" before execution.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you need the message to be sent before your command is run?

Comment: @RossWilson Because the script will eventually reboot the machine (it's a Raspberry Pi 3).

Comment: Arr, cool, cool. The only way I can see you getting around this would be to implement some sort of queue system or make a second call to after the "ok" to actually trigger the command.

Answer (score 0):

You want to flush() before calling sleep.

```
echo json_encode(["auth"=>"ok"]);
flush();
sleep(5);
exec("sudo /var/www/scripts/configwifi.sh \"".$ssid."\" \"".$wifipwd."\"");
```

Comment: Looks like PHP is not able to override the buffer flush, not even `ob_flush()` is working :$

Comment: I tried it CLI, not browser. Hopefully something comes up. One thing I'm thinking is after you get the response, use JS to call another PHP script 5 seconds after. I know it's not exactly what you're looking for per the question, however.

Comment: Actually I could just ignore the answer and assume that it went ok... or maybe put the sleep(5) inside the .sh file and execute it with '&' at the end so that it escapes the shell and let the php script finish. Gotta test that.

Comment: Weird, I'm doing:
<?php
echo json_encode(array('test' => 'something'));
flush();
sleep(2);
echo date('h:i:s');

and getting (in the browser):

{"test":"something"}

then two seconds later:

{"test":"something"}09:54:01

Granted, I'm not calling exec().